# Jenkins Groovy Script not recognizing windows Drive

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Using the following groovy script in my `Jenkinsfile` to do some file operations for preparing my build package:

```
pipeline {
    agent any    
    stages {
        stage('package-windows') {
            when {
                expression { isUnix() == false && env.JOB_NAME == 'my-job-webapi'}
            }
            steps {
                bat label: 'unzip all files', script: 'FOR /R .\\archive %%I IN (*.zip) DO "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x "%%I" -aou -o"%%~dpI\\*"'               
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

When i run the job its failing with the following error:

```
\Program was unexpected at this time.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\my-job-webapi>FOR /R .\archive \Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "~dpI\*"[Pipeline] }
```

For some reason its unable to recognize the drive letter `C:` in the path `"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"`. What is the right way to provide the path with windows drive letter in Groovy script ? Or is there a different way this needs to be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to use `/` instead of `\\`. `C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe` worked